# How to execute a query when a table does not exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a long query that needs to run on two different instances of postgres on two different servers. The postgres versions are 9.6 and 9.2 (unfortunately, they're old). Below is an example query that I would like to run independently on both databases and then combine the results using PHP:

```sql
SELECT
   table1.date,
   table1.amount,
   table2.count
FROM
   table1
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.date = table1.date;
```

The problem is that one database has a `table2`, but the other doesn't. Is there a way to have the query return null for `table2.count` if `table2` doesn't exist? Is my only option to write separate queries for each database?

Comment: You'll need separate queries.  the compiler will attempt to find table2 see it doesn't exist and indicate your SQL is invalid due to missing table object

Comment: I agree with @xQbert. The only thing I can think of is to embed the query in an **inline procedure** that will check for the existence of the table before running the query. The `DO` clause exists at least from PostgreSQL 9.x; see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-do.html

Comment: I consider it a hacky practice, but if the table with the same name isn't already in the second database, you could create `second_db.table2` as an empty identical table --`select * from first_db.table2 limit 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the table that exists using PostgreSQL information_schema. I write a sample function for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.my_select()
 RETURNS TABLE(p_date date, p_amount float4, p_count int4)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    
    if exists (
        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name = 'table2'
    ) then 
    
        return query 
        SELECT
           table1.date,
           table1.amount,
           table2.count::int4
        from table1
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.date = table1.date;
  
    else 
        return query 
        SELECT
           table1.date,
           table1.amount,
           null::int4 as "count"
        from table1;
    end if; 

END;
$function$;
```